# Android Studio debugger doesn't work when using C++ support

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, kotlin

I can't debug my **Java** classes or **Kotlin** files, all breakpoints has "x" signature , but it works for **cpp** class files

I'm using

**Android Studio version 2.2.2**

**OS version macOS siera 10.12**

**Gradle version 2.2.2**

this is my Module Build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "awesomethings.ge.takeapic"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the problem? Anything that might help someone reproduce it or understand what causes it: your OS, your software & build setup including versions, project layout etc.

Comment: I have updated my question